Spring jpa save entity with foreign fields
I have three entities:

Category: id, name
Brand: id, name
Product: id, name, category, brand

What is the best way to find category and brand from their repositories -> and setting them as fields for products?
I know how to do it one by one.
However, I want to know if there is a better way for this.
The current approach is:
var category = CategoryRepository.findById(category_id);
var product = BrandRepository.findById(brandId); 
product.category = category; 
product.brand = brand;


Please define better way. More abstract or shorter or more explainatory or more simple.

Do you set foreign fields like me or there are other optimized ways to make lesser database requests? If product entity have 10  foreign fields to 10 entity then it will load database much more.

Ah, lesser database requests. Thats a thing I can work with!
